# How to upgrade spring framework version in spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, maven

I am using spring-boot 2.3.3.RELEASE with the according spring-boot-starter-parent in maven.

```
<parent>
   <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
   <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
   <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
   <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
 </parent>
```

Due to the spring4shell CVE I wanted to upgrade the spring-framework to 5.2.20.RELEASE instead of the already included 5.2.8.RELEASE. I tried overriding the `spring-framework.version` property from spring-boot-dependencies.

```
    <spring-framework.version>5.2.20.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
```

But it did not work. I also looked up the spring-boot-starter-web-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom and it has the spring-web dependency hardcoded to 5.2.8.RELEASE.

Are there any other ways of upgrading the spring-framework version in spring-boot besides  adding all the new versions as dependencies to the `dependencyManagement` section?
Thx

Full POM:

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" 
  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" 
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 
  http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
<modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

<parent>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
  <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
  <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<groupId>group</groupId>
<artifactId>app</artifactId>
<version>3.1.0-SNAPSHOT</version>
<packaging>war</packaging>

<properties>
  <flyway.version>4.1.2</flyway.version>
  <groovy.version>2.4.20</groovy.version>
  <spring-framework.version>5.2.20.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
  <spring-cloud.version>Hoxton.SR7</spring-cloud.version>
  <h2.version>1.4.196</h2.version>
</properties>

<dependencyManagement>
<dependencies>

  <dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
    <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
    <type>pom</type>
    <scope>import</scope>
  </dependency>

</dependencies>
</dependencyManagement>

<dependencies>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-rest</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-webflux</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
  <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
  <artifactId>spring-boot-configuration-processor</artifactId>
  <optional>true</optional>
</dependency>

<dependency>
  <groupId>org.mockito</groupId>
  <artifactId>mockito-core</artifactId>
</dependency>


<dependency>
  <groupId>org.codehaus.groovy</groupId>
  <artifactId>groovy-all</artifactId>
  <version>${groovy.version}</version>
</dependency>

<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat/jackson-dataformat-xml -->
<dependency>
  <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat</groupId>
  <artifactId>jackson-dataformat-xml</artifactId>
</dependency>

</dependencies>
<build>
<finalName>app</finalName>
<resources>
  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>true</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/version.json</include>
      <include>**/**.properties</include>
    </includes>
  </resource>

  <resource>
    <directory>src/main/resources</directory>
    <filtering>false</filtering>
    <includes>
      <include>**/*.*</include>
    </includes>
    <excludes>
      <exclude>**/version.json</exclude>
      <exclude>**/**.properties</exclude>
    </excludes>
  </resource>
</resources>
</build>
</project>
```

**EDIT:**
This is a part of mvn dependency:tree:

```
+- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-webflux:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-json:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  |  +- com.fasterxml.jackson.datatype:jackson-datatype-jdk8:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  |  \- com.fasterxml.jackson.module:jackson-module-parameter-names:jar:2.11.2:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-reactor-netty:jar:2.3.3.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-web:jar:5.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  +- org.springframework:spring-webflux:jar:5.2.8.RELEASE:compile
[INFO] |  \- org.synchronoss.cloud:nio-multipart-parser:jar:1.1.0:compile
[INFO] |     \- org.synchronoss.cloud:nio-stream-storage:jar:1.1.3:compile
```

If you have a look at the `spring-boot-starter-webflux-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom` which includes the problematic spring-web 5.2.8.RELEASE you will find that the spring version is hardcoded to 5.2.8.RELEASE. So setting the `spring.framework` property in maven will have no effect.

```
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
      <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>
      <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>
      <scope>compile</scope>
    </dependency>
```

Output of mvn help:effective-pom:

```
 <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  <!-- org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.2.8.RELEASE, line 126 -->
        <artifactId>spring-web</artifactId>  <!-- org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.2.8.RELEASE, line 127 -->
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>  <!-- org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.2.8.RELEASE, line 128 -->
      </dependency>
      <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>  <!-- org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.2.8.RELEASE, line 131 -->
        <artifactId>spring-webflux</artifactId>  <!-- org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.2.8.RELEASE, line 132 -->
        <version>5.2.8.RELEASE</version>  <!-- org.springframework:spring-framework-bom:5.2.8.RELEASE, line 133 -->
      </dependency>
```

**Edit after Solution by @Inthai2002:**
I have additonally an internal lib pom imported in my pom.xml

```
<dependencyManagement>
        <dependencies>
            <dependency>
                <groupId>internal</groupId>
                <artifactId>lib</artifactId>
                <version>4.4.0</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>

            <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-cloud-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>${spring-cloud.version}</version>
                <type>pom</type>
                <scope>import</scope>
            </dependency>

        </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>
```

and this internal lib has the spring-boot-dependencies pom directly imported which leads to the fact that spring-framework.version property is ignored:

```
          <dependency>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-dependencies</artifactId>
                <version>2.3.3.RELEASE</version>
                <scope>import</scope>
                <type>pom</type>
            </dependency>
```

Comment: Is there a reason why you can not upgrade spring boot itself? current version: 2.6.6

Comment: QA guys do not have the time currently to run a full test...only upgrading minor spring framework version would require only a smoke test

Comment: As you're using `spring-boot-starter-parent`, setting `spring-framework.version` should be all that's necessary to override the version. Can you provide a complete `pom.xml` file that shows this not working?

Comment: if you are using spring boot you should only upgrade spring boot itself which implies upgrades of spring framework etc.... otherwise it makes no sense...and if you have people doing manually tests there is going something wrong... (no automatic tests?) I would Upgrade from 2.3.3.RELEASE to 2.3.4.RELEASE up to latest 2.3.X line...then go to 2.4.0... etc. because 2.3.3 line is out of support https://spring.io/projects/spring-boot#support and also 2.4.X line...

Comment: @khmarbaise there is a part of the tests automated, others which are not...upgrading spring boot is an option for me, but i would directly go to the latest 2.5.x version, i guess, which is on our roadmap, bit this rce requires a patch.

Comment: Upgrade is a continous process...every release upgrade ...small step small risk...less to do...

Comment: how do you know it did not work? Have you tried printing the dependency tree (mvn dependency:tree) and search for 5.2.8.RELEASE?

Comment: @lnthai2002 I looked up the maven dependency tree and I also verified that the included spring jars have still the 5.2.8.RELEASE version. Have a look at the OP Edit.

Comment: Can you try using this command to check where the version actually comes from: mvn help:effective-pom -Dverbose . I did an upgrade to sf 5.2.21 from 5.2.9 of spring boot 2.3.4 last week and that command showed me that the version is from spring-framework-bom which is the parent of spring-boot-starter-parent as I remember

Comment: @Inthai2002 ...yeah the version is coming from spring-framework-bom. I added a part of the output to the OP. But I could not verify that spring-framework-bom is the parent of spring-boot-starter-parent..in my case the parent is  spring-boot-dependencies. How could I change the version of spring-framework-bom?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just tried your pom (with and without the **spring-framework.version** property) on a clean m2 repo. Without the property, spring-framework is 5.2.8, with the property, it is 5.2.20. Can you try on a clean repo?

The **spring-framework-bom** at version X is hardcoded to all the spring packages for version X (see https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-framework-bom/5.2.8.RELEASE/spring-framework-bom-5.2.8.RELEASE.pom)

The **spring-framework.version** property is declared and used to pull the **spring-framework-bom** in **spring-boot-dependencies** and inherited by its descendants (see https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-dependencies/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-dependencies-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom).

**spring-boot-dependencies** is parent of **spring-boot-starter-parent** (see https://repo1.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/boot/spring-boot-starter-parent/2.3.3.RELEASE/spring-boot-starter-parent-2.3.3.RELEASE.pom).

Because the property is inherited by descendant, you can override its value at the pom of your application. By overriding it with 5.2.20, you are swapping out spring-framework-bom 5.2.8 for 5.2.20 which effectively pull most of the spring packages for 5.2.20

Comment: Thanks a lot...its working. I had another import pom dependency (not in the OP as internal lib) which included the spring-boot-dependencies pom directly and this was the reason the spring-framework.version property had no effect.

Comment: I had that too, some of my projects can't use spring-boot-starter-parent as ancestor thus they have to include spring-boot-dependencies as a dependency thus removing the effective of the spring-framework.version. Thus the solution is different for such case

Answer (score 1):

As per the official doc : https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/dependency-versions.html#appendix.dependency-versions.properties

```
<spring-framework.version>5.2.20.RELEASE</spring-framework.version>
```

will only override the versions for Group ID org.springframework and not to org.springframework.boot. I don't see a version property for spring boot, so might have to include the version in the dependency.

Comment: thanks for your answer, but I would like to only upgrade the spring-framework version and not spring-boot (which includes a newer version of spring-framework)

Answer (score -1):

Just change the parent node as below

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>2.6.6</version>
</parent>
```

Comment: this is how you would upgrade to spring-boot 2.6.6 but the question was how to upgrade only the spring framework version instead of spring-boot, as a spring boot upgrade is currently not feasible. thanks anyway.

Comment: What you did is right. But sometimes, you have to forcefully run "update project..." from your Maven plug-in to bring in the one you updated in your POM